# Making mask files for Tensorflow segmentation/object detection API

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, png, image-segmentation

In the article for creating a dataaset for the TF object detection API [[link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md#materializing-data-for-instance-segmentation-materializing-instance-seg)], users are asked to store an object mask as:

> a repeated list of single-channel encoded PNG strings, or a single dense 3D binary tensor where masks corresponding to each object are stacked along the first dimension

Since the article strongly suggests using a `repeated list of single-channel encoded PNG strings`, I would particularly be interested in knowing how to encode this. My annotations are typically from `csv` files, which I have no problem in generating the TFRecords file.  Are there any instructions somewhere on how to make this conversion?

Comment: Were you able to work on it?

Comment: Not yet. Will post here when I find out.

Comment: hi, do you know where i put or how to use the png mask in mask_rcnn object detection ?

Answer (score 0):

i make it works with pet dataset , on tensorflow you have 2 way with coco dataset tf record and with pet_tfrecord.

the first took JSON file 
the second take XML and PNG

there is one application VGG could make annotations in PNG or in JSON, then you use the directory tree needed, i used the pet dataset example. but finally mask is not displayed, even with the example dataset...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the array of png, I ended up using a dense tensor, where each pixel value represents a class.

Note,, I’ve seen many other people who didn’t use sequential numbers and ended up having problems later. The idea makes sense, if I have 2 classes, label 1 as 0 and the other as 255. The rationale is that when you see this in grayscale it is obvious what gets labeled 1 or 255. This is impossible when you use 0,1,2,... However, this violates a lot of assumptions in downstream code (e.g. deeplab)